# Upgrading from Rails 2 to 3: undefined method use_standard_json_time_format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Rails from 2.3 to 3.1. I watched the upgrade video from Railscast but I am having some difficulties.

Steps I followed:

1. Create a separate Rails 3 branch from stable branch.
2. Update and reload RVM to the latest version.
3. `gem install rails -v 3.0.20`.
4. `rails upgrade check` and `rails upgrade backup` using Rails upgrade plugin.
5. `rails new . --skip-active-record`

When I start the server I am getting this error:

```
initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb:13:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `use_standard_json_time_format=' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `use_standard_json_time_format` changed between Rails 3.0.20 and 3.1.0 from `false` to `true`, so depending which version you're aiming for (your question mentions both), you might be able to drop the configuration.

If you're cherry-picking ActiveSupport modules, make sure you've required `ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding`, which defines the method.

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/json/encoding'
```

And since `ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format` is just delegating to `ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding`, you can also try calling it directly on the latter.

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = true
```

Comment: Hello Kristján, thanks for your response. I am aiming for Rails 3.1.12

Comment: Hello Kristján, adding the require statements did the trick. Thanks